# How to retrieve the records of the Nth and the last Nth trading days within each period in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, finance, ranking, dolphindb

How to retrieve the records of the Nth trading day and the last Nth trading day for each period (such as a year, quarter, or month)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve records of the Nth trading day:

```
select * , rowNum-first(rowNum)  as  offset ,quarterEnd(end_date) as q from tradingday_rowno(2020.01.01,2021.01.01)  context by quarterEnd(end_date) csort end_date
```

To retrieve records of the last Nth trading day:

```
select * , rowNum-last(rowNum)  as  offset ,quarterEnd(end_date) as q from tradingday_rowno(2020.01.01,2021.01.01)  context by quarterEnd(end_date) csort end_date
```